# Angular - TodoMVC example

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working to understand Angular. As part of this, I began reviewing the TodoMVC example found [here](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/angular2). I notice that the app has both .js and .ts files. My question is, do developers have to write both of these?  I was under the impression that a developer writes the TypeScript (.ts) and it compiles to JavaScript (.js). If this is true, why would someone include the JavaScript files in the repo? Or, am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: If you look at the JS, it's just the compiled TS. It's not clear why they're shipping generated code, you'd have to ask the maintainers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write Angular2 application you write typescript files (TS).

When you run `npm start` or `ng serve` with angular-cli the ts file convert to js.

developer should only commit ts files to source control.

in this todomvc project the developer mistakenly put the js files.